# Trace [trace] and [tracing] together

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

What do you think about synonymazing [trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trace) and [tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tracing)?

I think they always have the same meaning, also their excerpts are quite similar:

[trace](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/trace/info):

> A trace is a log of execution of a process or method.

[tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tracing/info):

> Tracing is a specialized use of logging to record information about a
>   program's execution.

Comment: A trace is a noun. Tracing is the act of creating a trace.

Comment: @JL2210 you are right, but do we really want to have different tags for them? If question is tagged with `trace`, can't it be tagged with `tracing` and vice verca?

Comment: I suppose that would work.